# visNetwork: How do I extract visGetPositions() from shiny into R coordinates matrix?

Tags: r, shiny

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = "green")
  })

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    input$network_positions
  })
  observe({
    input$goButton
    visNetworkProxy("network") %>%
      visGetPositions()
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(10,visNetworkOutput("network", height = "100%"),
           verbatimTextOutput("test")),
    column(2, actionButton("goButton", "Go!"))
  )

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So visGetPositions only works in shiny. After you press Go, it calculates and prints out positions of each node. How do I extract it into R matrix so I can use it as coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be storing the coordinates in a `reactiveValues`, binding them together with `rbind`.  For example, replacing your observer with the following,

```
vals <- reactiveValues(coords=NULL)
observeEvent(input$goButton, {
  visNetworkProxy("network") %>% visGetPositions()
  vals$coords <- if (!is.null(input$network_positions)) 
                   do.call(rbind, input$network_positions)
})
```

It checks for NULL so the `do.call` doesn't error.  Then, the `output$test` changes to the following in order to check the result

```
output$test <- renderPrint( vals$coords )
```

#### update

A possible way to have the positions update without the button using `invalidateLater`:

```
output$test <- renderPrint( vals$coords )
vals <- reactiveValues(coords=NULL)
observe({
  invalidateLater(1000)
  visNetworkProxy("network") %>% visGetPositions()
  vals$coords <- if (!is.null(input$network_positions)) 
                   do.call(rbind, input$network_positions)
})
```

Comment: Hi, is there any automatic way the positions could be defined ? I have [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583493/vis-network-define-node-location?noredirect=1#comment115959013_65583493). Can you please have a look and appreciate any inputs.